# Shift each non-zero value in a 3D numpy array using a vectorized method

Tags: python, numpy

My problem is in 3D, but I will explain it in 2D.  Suppose I have a numpy array that is mostly zeros but a few ones.  (For my real problem, I have about a 1000 x 1000 x 1000 grid with about 10 to 1000 ones.)

```
positions = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I also have two other arrays (when in 2D) that tell me how I want to move the ones.  They might look like this:

```
shift_x = np.array([[0, 0,  0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, -1, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0,  0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0,  0, 0, 1],
                    [0, 0,  0, 0, 0]])

shift_y = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0,  0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 0,  0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0,  0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, -1],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0,  0]])
```

I then want to apply `shift_x` and `shift_y` to the `positions` array.  For example, the "1" in the second row of `positions` would move left (-1) and up (1), while the "1" in the fourth row would move right (wrapping around) and down.  The new array would look like this:

```
new_positions = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                          [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I realize I can write this as a for loop and move each item one at a time.  That is too slow for my needs.  I want a vectorized approach that utilizes numpy's capabilities.  Can someone suggest a set of vectorized operations that would accomplish this task?

I've written this previously as a for loop but, as mentioned, this is too slow when working with large 3D arrays.  This is done by shifting the index of the "one"s according to the `shift_x` and `shift_y` arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With arrays so big and sparse, have you considered using a data type different from NumPy arrays? Using plain `dict`s instead would allow you to only store the `1`s and not the `0`s, making the whole thing lighter and faster.

Even if sticking to NumPy arrays, achieving your desired operation through NumPy will most probably come with a huge memory waste. I would suggest trying a [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) solution instead, which works off of simple loop code.

Below I have a simple loop implementation, with and without Numba:

```py
from time import time
import numpy as np

positions = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

shift_x = np.array([[0, 0,  0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, -1, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0,  0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0,  0, 0, 1],
                    [0, 0,  0, 0, 0]])

shift_y = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0,  0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 0,  0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0,  0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, -1],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0,  0]])

def shift(positions, shift_x, shift_y):
    m = positions.shape[0]
    n = positions.shape[1]
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            if positions[i, j] == 0:
                continue
            positions[i, j] = 0
            dx = shift_x[i, j]
            dy = shift_y[i, j]
            positions[(i - dy)%m, (j + dx)%m] = 1

tic = time()
shift(positions, shift_x, shift_y)
toc = time()
print('no Numba:', toc - tic)


######## Numba version below #########


import numba

@numba.jit
def shift(positions, shift_x, shift_y):
    m = positions.shape[0]
    n = positions.shape[1]
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            if positions[i, j] == 0:
                continue
            positions[i, j] = 0
            dx = shift_x[i, j]
            dy = shift_y[i, j]
            positions[(i - dy)%m, (j + dx)%m] = 1

# Initial call, just for compiling
tmp = np.zeros((2, 2), dtype=int)
shift(tmp, tmp, tmp)

# Actual call
tic = time()
shift(positions, shift_x, shift_y)
toc = time()
print('Numba:', toc - tic)
```

Even for this very small example, Numba provides a measureable speedup. For large arrays, it will be very significant.

Note that I first call the Numba function with "fake data". This first call is slower than future calls due to compilation, so it's best to provide small (in data size) arguments here, and they should be of the same NumPy `dtype` as your actual arrays.

Comment: Please note that the modulus is a very expensive operation (especially in Python/Numba). It is certainly better to use a conditional instead, especially since the value will most of the time a wrapping around will certainly not be needed (and the processor can predict the branch outcome). Anyway, sparse matrices are certainly the way to go indeed.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Fair point, swapping `%` for `if` can bring some additional speed up. Out of interest, is it really the case that `%` is *especially* expensive *in Numba*? I would have imagined that this compiled down to as an efficient instruction as can be, given the operation.

Comment: In Python, operation are interpreted so they are slow. Numba generate a pretty efficient set of instruction to compute the modulus compared to Python, but still, it is not so efficient because it has to *behave the same way Python does* and this introduces an overhead compared to native modulus instructions. Python requires negative numbers modulus N to be in the range `[0;N[` while the native `div`/`idiv` instruction can result in negative numbers. Besides `div` and `idiv` are expensive, especially with 64-bit integers, and I expect `m` to be a 64-bit integer.

Comment: Note that replacing `%m` by `%1000` should also be significantly faster because the JIT compiler can generate a set of fast instructions performing some integer tricks instead of a slow `div`/`idiv` one. This requires the array size to be fixed at compile-time though.

Comment: Ah right, so there's an extra check for negativity compared to bare C (on top of integer module just being expensive). In my example code above they are 64-bit, but if all shifts are `±1` one should of course use 8-bit (e.g. `dtype=np.int8`). Or I guess 16-bit since the dimension (`1000`) does not fit in 8 bit?

Comment: This is awesome!  I tried this on a smaller 100 x 100 x 100 grid with 1000 ones and ran it over 200 shifts.  The vanilla for loop takes 25 seconds.  The numba for loop takes 0.5 seconds.  50-fold speed up!